# Emulating a CreditCard via HCE

Tags: android, nfc, payment, hce, emv

I´m trying to develop an application that emulates a creditcard over HCE on Android (4.4). I have a target application that can read from an NFC-sticker and I am now hoping to achieve the same result by emulating the NFC on my device. The application supports reading ISO 14443-4 Type A/IsoDep wich is good since that is what I am emulating. The format the application reads as I understand it is: "B5105105105105100^CARDDATA^121222200000181000000,5105105105105100=121222200000181000000" (In this example I use a MC testcard number). The goal is to get the target application to recieve the data I send in a correct format and I am yet to achieve this. I have tried to check up on other examples but they are hard to find and my knowledge is somewhat limited at this point.

I´ve set up the AID the target application is requiring in my apduservice.xml

The question now is how do I send the correct data to the target application? I want to send both track1 "B5105105105105100^CARDDATA^121222200000181000000" and track2 "5105105105105100=121222200000181000000" Do I need to verify the apdu part somehow via AID/PPSE more than through the apduservice file?

I´ve tried the following with no success:

### Code:

```
public static String pan = "B5105105105105100^CARDDATA^121222200000181000000,5105105105105100=121222200000181000000";

@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] apdu, Bundle extras) {
    byte[] response = new byte[] {};

    return response = pan.getBytes();
}
```

What am I missing? Thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing that credit cards are not simple memory tags. Instead, they communicate using a rather complex protocol (consisting of a file structure according to ISO 7816-4 and using specific commands to instruct the card to select applications, to return file data, to perform transactions, etc). The credit card protocols are specified by EMVCo and can be found [here](http://www.emvco.com/).

Answer (score 1):

As an example you can check out this project (https://bitbucket.org/tbellenger/hce_mobile_card/commits/52c7081cca5017638d4a74e40cb44a4bd7efb7f6). Don't go past this commit though as the new code breaks functionality. The app is able to read a paywave or paypass credit card via NFC and store the information from the card in the phone. Then if you tap the phone against a contactless payment terminal it will send the information that it received from the phone. There is a helper library that you will need here (https://bitbucket.org/tbellenger/card_tools). Good luck.

Comment: Hello @tbellenger , i dont know if currently up to today this repository still can be helpfull,  how can i be able to run your project?

Comment: Any update on this how to use it? i was unable to run it.